# Highcharts tooltip on click mailto

Tags: onclick, highcharts, tooltip

How to create a link to an email with address based on data xAxis in highcharts tooltip without changing its contents?

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return ("<a href='mailto:example@me.com'><span class='xAxis'>" + this.y + "</span></a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Link need to be opened in new window or use mailto function? http://jsfiddle.net/ZV3mT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution is to create your own positioner, so tooltip will be always under cursor: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner. Of course this is still not perfect solution, but should allow to click part of the tooltip (just make it more accurate for your case).